# Why would a laptop power off due to Raspberry Pico + servo?

Tags: servo, hobbyist

For learning purposes I used Raspberry Pico to control a servo motor (using PWM.)

I used an [SG-5010 servo.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/155)

I powered the servo from the Raspberry Pico (which was itself USB-attached to my laptop), GND(brown) ->  pin 38 (GND), "+"(red) to pin 40 (named VBUS), orange to pin 16.

I wrote a simple program:

```
from machine import Pin, PWM
from time import sleep

pwm = PWM(Pin(16))
pwm.freq(1000)
while True:
    pwm.duty_u16(1000)
    sleep(1)
    pwm.duty_u16(60123)
    sleep(1)
```

It worked fine for about a minute, then my laptop went blank momentarily.

Luckily, it works fine now (I'm typing from it.)

What happened?

- Did I do a stupid thing by powering the servo from the laptop?
- Should I have used a capacitor?
- Should I limit in time the PWM?

Comment: How can we know what happened? Are you sure it was not a screen saver blanking the screen because it was idle? Which servo it is, how much current servo and otjer components require, and how much your USB port can provide? Also at this point you do realize that one mistake with whatever you are building can simply fry your laptop and all data on it with a blink of an eye, so you may not want to experiment on your best computer which you don't want to get fried.

Comment: @Justme frankly, only after this I realized the threat. I now plan to setup a raspberry Pi 3 just to work with the raspberry Pico - and not to damage my laptop.
My USB is probably a standard one - 5V/1A. (I've added details about the servo)

Comment: I also though I did a kind of a typical mistake - I just don't know which one.

Comment: The link is useless. It does not have any information how much current the servo needs. Also what does it mean when the laptop went blank, did screen really go blank for a moment with no other effect or did it reboot or what?

Comment: @Justme it was shut off - in a blink of an eye, yeah. I unplugged everything, then pushed "power" button - luckyly, it turned on.

Comment: I sadly don't know more details.
Ok - do people use a spare, e.g. raspberry pi board to play with such things? I should I have had a separate power source for the servo? I should I always know the max current?

Comment: They isolate the laptop from the tested devices. Either transistors or relays can often provide sufficient isolation.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the servo drew so much current from the laptop that the laptop reacted as though there were a short circuit on the USB bus.

You should **not** power the servo from the Raspberry Pico or the laptop USB.  Servos can draw more than an ampere of current - that can cause the Pico to shutdown or the laptop to detect a short circuit on the USB bus.

Use a separate power supply for the servo.  Tie the servo power supply ground to the ground of the Pico so that the servo will properly understand the PWM from the Pico.